# Circleci Ubuntu 14.04 build image has multiple gopath values

Tags: go, circleci

The CircleCI Ubuntu 14.04 build image has the following value for the GOPATH env var:

```
/home/ubuntu/.go_workspace:/usr/local/go_workspace
```

and no GOROOT env var.  Is this an error?

Comment: [GOPATH](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable): `The GOPATH environment variable lists places to look for Go code. On Unix, the value is a colon-separated string.`

Answer (score 3):

`GOROOT` is the enviroment variable that specify where the go binary distribution is installed, if is installed in the default folder you are not required to declare this enviroment variable.
And, according to [CIRCLE CI docs](https://circleci.com/docs/language-go/) Go is installed in the default folder so you shouldn't have any problem.